# Find the maximum probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given $\xi$ is a normally distributed random variable with $E(\xi)=0$ and $Var(\xi)=\sigma^2$. Find such $\sigma$  that $P(\xi \in (1;3))$ is maximized.

---

I found only numerical solution in EXCEL. $\Phi (\frac{3}{\sigma})-\Phi (\frac{1}{\sigma}) \rightarrow max.$  $\sigma \approx 1.4$.

What about analytical solution? I have no any idea.

Comment: I'm confused. Is $\xi$ normally distributed? And you are looking for $\sigma$ s.t. $P(\xi \in (1,3)$ is maximized?

Comment: Yes! $\xi$ is normally distributed I'm looking for $\sigma$ s.t P is maximized!

Comment: Well $P(\xi \in (1,3))$ is maximized when $\sigma \rightarrow 0$, in which case $P(\xi \in (1,3)) \rightarrow 1$. So I am not sure if this is really what you are asking for

Comment: Proof it please!

Comment: Sure, it's not the case!

Comment: Whups, my bad. Read $-1$ instead of $1$.

Answer (score 3):

Your numerical solution is wrong. The analytical solution shows that

$$P(1<X<3)=P\left(\frac{1}{\sigma}<Z< \frac{3}{\sigma} \right)=\int_{1/\sigma}^{3/\sigma}\phi(t)dt$$

this is the quantity to be maximized. Thus let's take the derivative obtaining

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-9/(2\sigma^2)}\cdot\frac{-3}{\sigma^2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-1/(2\sigma^2)}\cdot\frac{-1}{\sigma^2}$$

Set it $=0$ obtaining

$$e^{-1/(2\sigma^2)}=3\cdot e^{-9/(2\sigma^2)}$$

taking the log immediately you find the solution

$$\sigma^2=\frac{4}{\log3}$$

that is $\sigma \approx 1.9081$

Comment: And Excel produces the same value when varying `A1` to maximise `=NORM.DIST(3,0,A1,TRUE)-NORM.DIST(1,0,A1,TRUE)`